# How to set the Linux kernel to use transparent huge pages of 1GB page size?

Tags: linux, memory-management, linux-kernel, tlb, huge-pages

I am using the 5.14 kernel, and I saw this option （CONFIG_HAVE_ARCH_TRANSPARENT_HUGEPAGE_PUD=y） in the compilation configuration.

Does it mean that I can use 1GB sized transparent huge pages instead of 2MB THP? How should this feature be enabled?

Comment: You can reserve memory for hugepages with kernel commandline arguments.  If you try to allocate later it can either fail or fall back to smaller chunks. https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.14/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.html

Comment: @stark Can "hugepagesz" parameter affect transparent huge pages? Or can it only affect huge pages obtained by explicit requests?

Comment: Nope. It only affects persistent hugepages reserved at boot. THP only does 2M, I believe.